# How do I create a Lightbox with images called from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, uikit, lightbox

I'm trying to implement a Lightbox gallery where clicking an image link launches a slideshow of images that are loaded from an array, not from inline content on the page. All the examples I can find use a group of inline images. I am using a framework called UIkit (https://https://getuikit.com/docs/introduction) which has a "lightbox" class.

My Html looks like this:

```
<div class="uk-child-width-1-3@m" uk-grid uk-lightbox="animation: fade">
    <div>
        <a class="uk-inline" href="images/dark.jpg">
            <img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="uk-inline" href="images/light.jpg">
            <img src="images/dark.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="uk-inline" href="images/photo.jpg">
            <img src="images/light.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone think of a way to implement the lightbox using the images called from the array so we don't have to see each individual image on the actual page (one image links to a lightbox containing more of that theme) and what the JS/html would look like?

Thank you in advance! Still new to JS and learning! : )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they have an [api you could use](https://getuikit.com/docs/lightbox#javascript)

```js
const button = document.getElementById('my-button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {

  const panel = UIkit.lightboxPanel({
    items: [
    {
        source: 'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/eb9/hot-coffee-1240214.jpg',
        caption: 'item 1'
      },
      {
        source: 'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/57a/time-2-1240218.jpg',
        caption: 'item 2'
      },
    ]
  });

  panel.show()
})
```

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.6.18/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.6.18/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.6.18/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>

<button id="my-button">Show</button>
```